# JavaFX secondary stage onCloseRequest

Tags: javafx, event-handling, eventhandler

I have a little issue close a secondary stage after clicking the close at the top right corner.
I'm using fxml with controller class, i need a way to handle this situation.

Here is what i do but i get a nullpointer exception :

```
   @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        Stage stage = (Stage) tbTabPaneHome.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        });

    }
```

Because the stage not yet intialized completly, so any other ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `Scene` nor the `Stage` are created yet, you can't call them or you get a NPE, as you already mentioned.

One way to install the event handler on the stage will be listening to changes in the `sceneProperty()` of `tbTabPaneHome`.

Once the node is added to the scene, that property will give you the `Scene` instance.

But the scene is not added to the `Stage` yet, so you need to wait till this is done, with `Platform.runLater()`:

```
public void initialize() {
    tbTabPaneHome.sceneProperty().addListener((obs, oldScene, newScene) -> {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            Stage stage = (Stage) newScene.getWindow();
            stage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
                Platform.exit();
                System.exit(0);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to deal with your secondary stage entirely in the main stage controller?

I want to hide or show a help windows from a button or help menu in my main application controller. Something like the following:

```
public Button helpBtn;
Stage anotherStage = new Stage();
boolean secondaryInitialyzed = false;
boolean secondaryShowing = false;
public void showOrHideHelp(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
if (!secondaryInitialyzed){
    Parent anotherRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("mySecondaryStage.fxml"));
    anotherStage.setTitle("Secondary stage");
    Scene anotherScene = new Scene(anotherRoot, 500, 350);
    anotherStage.setScene(anotherScene);
    secondaryInitialyzed = true;
}
if (secondaryShowing){
    anotherStage.hide();
    secondaryShowing = false;
    helpBtn.setText("Show Help");
}
else {
    anotherStage.show();
    secondaryShowing = true;
    helpBtn.setText("Hide Help");
}
```

It does work, and there might be a way for you to handle your setOnCloseRequest within the main controller.

I have the opposing issue, i.e preventing closing the secondary stage window by clicking the close at the top right corner. I'll look into setOnCloseRequest and see if there is a way there.

I also have an other unrelated problem: can I position the secondary in reference to the primary one?